# Seed_fu default object data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, seeding

Is this the best way to create default options for seed_fu data?

```
# /db/fixtures/development/accounts.rb
default_opts = { id: 1, employees: true, time_zone_id: 6, credit: true }

Account.seed(:id,
  default_opts.clone.merge!(id: 1),
  default_opts.clone.merge!(id: 2)
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track. You can simplify a bit though:

```
defaults = { employees: true, time_zone_id: 6, credit: true }

Account.seed(:id,
  defaults.update(id: 1, something_else: "asdf"),
  defaults.update(id: 2, something_else: "qwer")
)
```

Basically, if you don't `merge!` (which overwrites the original hash) then you don't need to first `clone` the hash. Also, I used `update` instead of `merge` because I feel that's the new Rails convention... since `ActiveRecord::Persistence#updates_attributes` has been renamed to just [`ActiveRecord::Persistence#update`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-update), for example. And because, IMO, `Hash#update` makes it more obvious which way the options are getting merged (left or right). And, finally, no need to define `id: 1` in the defaults hash, and, since it's not common to all records, you should leave it out so as not to confuse.

Otherwise, yes. This is how I've been doing this sort of things for years now and am quite happy with the approach.